# What Zelda theme is this?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda, music-identification

A theme appears right at the start of this video (from 0:00 to 0:20) and pops up often throughout many of the movements from the Zelda Symphony.

In this instance, it goes like this:

F# (HIGH), C#, A, B, F# (LOW), E, F# (LOW)
F# (HIGH), C#, A, B, F# (LOW), E

This theme/motif shows up almost as frequently as the [main theme for *The Legend of Zelda*](https://youtu.be/6Qp-ypYp6rQ?t=6m39s), so I would assume it is a pretty major theme from the *Zelda* video games but I don't recognize it.

What theme is this? Is it associated with a certain character, item, or location from the games?

Comment: NOTE: I am asking here on SFF because I'm more likely to get an answer from avid, knowledgeable fans here, whereas MusicFans.SE would be more casual fans.

Comment: there's a dedicated Stack Exchange for Gaming though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like it's arranged version of the Triforce chamber theme from *A Link to the Past*:

[Zelda wiki](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/The_Legend_of_Zelda_25th_Anniversary_Special_Orchestra_CD) seems to  agree with me, listing it as going from 0:00 to 0:22.

> "The Legend of Zelda 25th Anniversary Medley"
>
> 00:00 Triforce Chamber from *A Link to the Past*

It might have been used in the later games but I can't recall those for sure.

Comment: yep, as I have stated on the chat before, it is.

Answer (score -4):

It's called the "Legend of Zelda 25th Anniversary medley" on the 25th anniversary soundtrack and it even says this on the video itself (at the bottom).

Comment: I am not asking "What's the name of this video?", rather I was asking about the specific theme that occurs in the first 20 seconds of the video. The video is medley of several diferent music themes from the Zelda games, most of which I recognized. The very first one is the one I didn't recognize, so that's what I was asking about - "What specific theme is heard from 0-20 sec.s in this video? Does it represent a certain item, person, or loaction from the Zelda games?" [See Relix's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121410/54827)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the entire video of the whole 40 minutes, the first track is indeed of the name I gave you.